# Visual Basic | IF, ELSE not working inside DO WHILE loop

Tags: vba, excel

So, I am a little new to Visual Basic and was trying to create a macro on excel. The macro should ideally go through a column and separate the rows with value say, "WB" from the other values, say "EC" and compute based on that.

The problem is that the variables storing WB values are all zero and the variables storing the EC values in fact have the entire data computations.

```
Sub Button2_Click()  
Dim i As Integer, TotalEffortEC As Double, TotalNCEC As Double, TotalSizeEC As Double  
Dim TotalEffortWB As Double, TotalNCWB As Double, TotalSizeWB As Double  

TotalEffortEC = 0  
TotalNCEC = 0  
TotalSizeEC = 0  
TotalEffortWB = 0  
TotalNCWB = 0  
TotalSizeWB = 0  
i = 3  
Do While Worksheets("Valid Data").Cells(i, 6).Value <> ""  
    If Cells(i, 7).Value = "WB" Then  
        TotalEffortWB = Worksheets("Valid Data").Cells(i, 23).Value + TotalEffortWB  
        TotalNCWB = Worksheets("Valid Data").Cells(i, 14).Value + TotalNCWB  
        TotalSizeWB = Worksheets("Valid Data").Cells(i, 13).Value + TotalSizeWB  
    Else  
        TotalEffortEC = Worksheets("Valid Data").Cells(i, 23).Value + TotalEffortEC  
        TotalNCEC = Worksheets("Valid Data").Cells(i, 14).Value + TotalNCEC  
        TotalSizeEC = Worksheets("Valid Data").Cells(i, 13).Value + TotalSizeEC  
    End If  
    i = i + 1  
Loop  
Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2").Value = (TotalEffortEC + Range("B10") + Range("C10")) / TotalNCEC  
Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value = (TotalEffortEC + Range("B10") + Range("C10")) / TotalSizeEC  

Worksheets("Summary").Range("A3").Value = (TotalEffortWB + Range("B11") + Range("C11")) / TotalNCWB  
Worksheets("Summary").Range("B3").Value = (TotalEffortWB + Range("B11") + Range("C11")) / TotalSizeWB  
End Sub
```

The WB part of the code doesn't seem to run and it seems only the EC part is running irrespective of the validity of the condition. Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it normal that you make your loop by testing column F and take result from column G ?

Comment: Are you sure column `7` contains any `WB`s? Check for spaces and lower/upper case.

Comment: Another note is, you should specify which sheet Cells(i, 7).value = "WB" is refering to. Guess it should be the Valid Data sheet in this case?

Comment: Try running step-by-step (F8), and when you get to a "WB", highlight the `Cells(i, 7).Value` part and hover mouse over it. You can also add a watch by right clicking and selecting `Add Watch`. This is to see if it really says "WB". My guess is that it does not, because the `If` structure actually works in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Alex4336 you're surely referencing the wrong `Worksheet` object to which belong the `Range` and `Cells` collections to be accessed (***parent `Worksheet` object***), mixing qualified objects plus member access syntax (`.Range` and `.Cells`) and the use of *"global"* `Range` and `Cells` collections (bound to an **active  `Worksheet` *object***).

This makes your code inconsistent and source of potential problems.

You can avoid *repetitive qualifying expressions* and **gain readability, consistency and performances** simply by introducing **`With`** statement ([*see MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wc500chb.aspx)) this way:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim i As Integer, TotalEffortEC As Double, TotalNCEC As Double, TotalSizeEC As Double
Dim TotalEffortWB As Double, TotalNCWB As Double, TotalSizeWB As Double

    TotalEffortEC = 0
    TotalNCEC = 0
    TotalSizeEC = 0
    TotalEffortWB = 0
    TotalNCWB = 0
    TotalSizeWB = 0
    i = 3

    With Worksheets("Valid Data")
        Do While .Cells(i, 6).Value <> ""
            If .Cells(i, 7).Value = "WB" Then
                TotalEffortWB = .Cells(i, 23).Value + TotalEffortWB
                TotalNCWB = .Cells(i, 14).Value + TotalNCWB
                TotalSizeWB = .Cells(i, 13).Value + TotalSizeWB
            Else
                TotalEffortEC = .Cells(i, 23).Value + TotalEffortEC
                TotalNCEC = .Cells(i, 14).Value + TotalNCEC
                TotalSizeEC = .Cells(i, 13).Value + TotalSizeEC
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With

    With Worksheets("Summary")
        .Range("A2").Value = (TotalEffortEC + .Range("B10") + .Range("C10")) / TotalNCEC
        .Range("B2").Value = (TotalEffortEC + .Range("B10") + .Range("C10")) / TotalSizeEC
        .Range("A3").Value = (TotalEffortWB + .Range("B11") + .Range("C11")) / TotalNCWB
        .Range("B3").Value = (TotalEffortWB + .Range("B11") + .Range("C11")) / TotalSizeWB
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: adn Alex4336 - Thanks a ton for your help. It works well now.